# How to get last touch in ccTouchesMoved?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, touch

I'm working with cocos2d. How to get last touch in ccTouchesMoved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a global Variable in your ccTouchesBegan,

```
CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
startPosition = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchPoint];
```

in your ccTouchesMoved just use startPosition to check whether your hand moved

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex: 0];
    // The last location you touch
    CGPoint lastLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:self.view];
    // Current location
    CGPoint currentLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view]; 
}
```

You can do like that :)